# Why does the ruler and straightedge construction assume a segment of length $1$?

Tags: proof-explanation, contest-math, geometric-construction

I was reading practising for Math Olympiads and reading a bit about field extensions with the compass and straightedge constructions and though all steps are straight-forward, one thing bugs me:
They all assume a segment of length $1$ already given.
Take for example: [Exemplary Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction#Constructible_points_and_lengths) - Multiplication, division and square roots all rely on this assumption.

Why is this so and doesn't this violate the principles of compass and straightedge construction?
Furthermore, am I allowed to assume a segment of length $1$ as given?

Comment: You need it for dimensional reasons: $ab$ is measured in square meters instead of meters, so you need to know how long the unit "1" is just to make sense of what you should construct. Same with $\sqrt{a}$ or $a/b$. For instance $a/b$ is a scalar, so there isn't any natural "segment of length $a/b$" unless you fix the length of "1". On the other hand if you had given segments of lengths $a,b,c$ then you could construct $ab/c$ or $\sqrt{ab}$ without any extra "1"  because the units agree.

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek That makes a lot of sense, thanks!
Would you like to make this into an answer to get it off the unanswered questions list?
Can I reference this in Mathematical Olympiads?